# SQL Pivot that allows me to see which users have access to certain screens

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've got the following tables (in SQL Server):

Screen Access

```
+----+------+--------------+
| id | user | screen       |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | John | Screen 1     |
| 2  | Bob  | Screen 1     |
| 2  | Bob  | Screen 3     |
| 2  | Bob  | Screen 4     |
+----+------+--------------+
```

How do I create a pivot / a list showing which screens john has access to that bob does not?

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: only two users correct, but many screens, i just showed limited screens as an example.

Desired output

```
Users   |John|Bob
Screen1 |x   |x
Screen3 |    |x
Screen4 |    |x
```

Thank you.

Comment: you have only two user?

Comment: John doesn't have access to any screens that Bob does not.   What makes you think you need a pivot?   What would your desired output look like?

Comment: Updated my question with desired output

Comment: This is the 3rd PIVOT question today. What happened to research? BTW - Not my downvote, but please research a little.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot seems like overkill, but it is possible:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ScreenAccess
       PIVOT (Count(ID)
             FOR [User] IN (Bob,
                            John)) piv
```